# Why doesn't OpenCL bother if I allocate massive amounts of memory with clCreateBuffer?

Tags: opencl

Does it only matter if the buffer starts being used? I allocated a few buffers of a few gigabytes each that in total exceed 10 times the VRAM (or RAM) and the software didn't seem to bother. It only bothered if a single buffer exceeded a total global amount (in which case it returned invalid buffer size).

Comment: Depends on the implementation, but yea, since buffers are tied to the context and not the device the actual physical allocation is usually deferred until you write to it.

Comment: You should probably show the code you used to generate these buffers.

Comment: Why? It's reliably reproducible by anyone; the platform is AMD in case others deal with it differently.